# Collection list to grouped collection list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to create new lists based on grouping on some property and use the same to generate MVC View.

I have following structure

```
class ItemLine
{
   string SomeProperty { get; set; } 
   string SomeProperty1 { get; set; } 
   string SomeProperty2 { get; set; } 
}

class Item
{
   IEnumerable<ItemLine> ItemLines { get; set; }
}

Class Order
{
   IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Item class is received as Model to the view.
Now I want to create multiple IEnumerable based on someProperty

e.g.

```
-Order-
       -Item-
              -ItemLine-
                         -someProperty = 123-
                         -someProperty1-
                         -someProperty2-
              -ItemLine-
                         -someProperty = 234-
                         -someProperty1-
                         -someProperty2-
              -ItemLine-
                         -someProperty = 345-
                         -someProperty1-
                         -someProperty2-
       -Item-
              -ItemLine-
                         -someProperty = 123-
                         -someProperty1-
                         -someProperty2-
              -ItemLine-
                         -someProperty = 456-
                         -someProperty1-
                         -someProperty2-
       -Item-
              -ItemLine-
                         -someProperty = 345-
                         -someProperty1-
                         -someProperty2-


Output needed is


    -Order-
           -Item-
                  -ItemLine-
                             -someProperty = 123-
                             -someProperty1-
                             -someProperty2-
                  -ItemLine-
                             -someProperty = 123-
                             -someProperty1-
                             -someProperty2-    
                  -ItemLine-
                             -someProperty = null/blank-
                             -someProperty1-
                             -someProperty2-                                 
            -Item-               
                  -ItemLine-
                             -someProperty = 234-
                             -someProperty1-
                             -someProperty2-
                  -ItemLine-             
                             -someProperty = null/blank-
                             -someProperty1-
                             -someProperty2-    
                  -ItemLine-             
                             -someProperty = null/blank-
                             -someProperty1-
                             -someProperty2-                                 
           -Item-

                  -ItemLine-
                             -someProperty = 345-
                             -someProperty1-
                             -someProperty2-
                  -ItemLine-
                             -someProperty = 345-
                             -someProperty1-
                             -someProperty2-
                  -ItemLine-             
                             -someProperty = null/blank-
                             -someProperty1-
                             -someProperty2-                                 
            -Item-               
                  -ItemLine-
                             -someProperty = 456-
                             -someProperty1-
                             -someProperty2-
                  -ItemLine-
                             -someProperty = null/blank
                             -someProperty1-
                             -someProperty2-
                  -ItemLine-
                             -someProperty = null/blank
                             -someProperty1-
                             -someProperty2-
```

I have tried few things but am not able to achieve this can some one please suggest how to do this using linq.

Thanks!!!

Update : I have tried following but it outputs duplicates and I think its not best practice.

One of the requirements is that the new lists/collections must have same number of ItemLines as the maximum number of ItemLines in any Item in the collection, with the "extra" ItemLines having null, blank or default values for their properties.

```
foreach (var items in Model)
{
    foreach (var item in hm.Items)
    {
        var x = Model.SelectMany(u => u.Items).Where(u => u.ItemNo.Equals(item.ItemNo)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: what have try already?

Comment: Can you explain the null/blank- values and why they're not grouped together like the other values? Are you just saying each item needs to have 3 itemlines? You didn't explicitly say that anywhere.

Comment: I see 0 effort to find a solution yourself.

Comment: @teovankot I have updated what I have tried.

Comment: @itsme86 updated the requirement.

Comment: @Jakotheshadows I have tried few things but they have not worked that why I have posted here.

Comment: If it outputs duplicates, have you tried using `Distinct`?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid since the Model is a collection/list it generates duplicates and the var x is inside foreach loop and m using x to perform some further activities to data in x

Comment: Why do you have some items with null/blank itemlines in the expected output? what does that mean? Especially when the last item in the expected output doesn't have any of the null/blank itemlines. You really need to think about whether or not your question makes sense to other people.

Comment: @Jakotheshadows i am trying to create a comparison screen where user  can compare different items and itemlines and m doing this using a javascript function that transposes rows to columns. so for that function to work I need to placed same Itemlines from different items in a same collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the nicest way to do this, but since you have the criteria of needing to have all the `Item`s containing the same number of `ItemLine`s, this is what I could figure out (and would love to see how someone else would do this):

```
// Group the data out of your model organized by the SomeProperty value
// Order it by the number of items in the list so we know the first group will have the maximum number of values we'd need
var orderedGroups = Model.Items
    .SelectMany(itm => itm.ItemLines)
    .GroupBy(itm => itm.SomeProperty)
    .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count());

// Find out how many ItemLines you'd want to have in any 1 Item
var count = orderedGroups.First().Count();

// Create the output
var output = new Order() { 
                Items = orderedGroups
                .Select(grp => 
                    new Item() 
                    {
                        ItemLines = new ItemLine[count]
                        .Select((s,i) => grp.ElementAtOrDefault(i) ?? new ItemLine())
                    }
                )};
```

---

**Update:**

Given the comment made, I'm assuming your `Model` is simply an IEnumerable of `Item` rather than an `Order`. That being the case, simply replace the first line to:

```
// Group the data out of your model ordganized by the SomeProperty value
// Order it by the number of items in the list so we know the first group will have the maximum number of values we'd need
var orderedGroups = Model
    .SelectMany(itm => itm.ItemLines)
    .GroupBy(itm => itm.SomeProperty)
    .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count());
```

All the rest can stay the same.

Hope this does the trick.

Comment: thanks but I am not getting Model.Items instead the option available is Model.SelectMany / Select. I did mention that Model is equivalent to Order class i.e. a collection of Item but there is no direct property Items in Model.

Comment: I don't get what your Model class is, then, @NikhilGupta - The example you're providing in your question doesn't make sense then. Can you please update it to be correct so I could understand. Otherwise, it's near-impossible to help you.

Comment: @NikhilGupta, I'm going to GUESS your `Model` is simply an IEnumerable of `Item` and will update the answer accordingly... Hope this does the trick....

Comment: i did already change that but I was not able to update the statement var output = new Order line. What shall I change there. I dont have any class like Order.

Comment: Then please update your question - I answered based upon what you said you have and don't know what to tell you since it seems the information you provided is incorrect. OR create the `Order` class if ti seems appropriate.

Comment: i have added a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054814/list-of-orders-to-grouped-orders-using-linq) can you please take a look.