# List of Orders to Grouped Orders using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class Order like

```
class Order
{
   IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Item class looks like

```
class Item
{
   string SomeProperty { get; set; } 
   string SomeProperty1 { get; set; } 
   string SomeProperty2 { get; set; } 
}
```

Model is a list of Order like

```
@model IEnumerable<Order>
```

I want to group same Items in one order means grouping on `Item.SomeProperty`

I can achieve this by following ([Collection list to grouped collection list using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021620/collection-list-to-grouped-collection-list-using-linq))

```
var orderedGroups = Model
    .SelectMany(order => order.Items)
    .GroupBy(order => order.ItemNo)
    .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count()).ToList();
```

With this I want to make sure all groups have the same number of items, depending on the maximum count and adding "blank" results to the groups which has lower count but I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: You might be missing a Select at the end.

Comment: Not sure you can do this purely with linq. If you know how many you want you can use .Where count = x, but if not then you need to add some logic. What happens if you have a 6 groups with count: 33 22 11 ?

Comment: @zivweissman if there r 6 Orders with  few having 3 items few having 2 items and few having 1 item then the grouped collection will have 3 items each in all orders and some of the Orders will have one r two blank items. I need to deign a compare screen where grouped items needs to be compared and need to display blank items as well to make html look proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requirements are quite strange, not sure of the use case, but this is how I would achieve it:

```
var orderedGroups = Model
    .SelectMany(order => order.Items)
    .GroupBy(order => order.ItemNo)
    .OrderByDescending(order => order.Count())
    .ToDictionary(order => order.Key, order => order.ToList());
```

`orderedGroups` will be of type `Dictionary<string,List<Item>>`, assuming `ItemNo` is a string

Fetch the max number of elements in the `Descending sorted collection`:

```
var maxElements = orderedGroups.First().Value.Count; // Max elements collection is at the top

foreach (var x in orderedGroups.Skip(1)) // Skip the processing of first collection, as that has maximum number of elements
        {       
            int yMax = maxElements - x.Value.Count ; // Count of each Item collection

            for (int y = 0; y < yMax; y++)
            {
                x.Value.Add(default(Item)); // Adding `default Item`, replace with any standard value
            }
        }
```

Another working version of code using `Integer` in place of `Item`:

```
List<int> testList = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,1,3,5,6,3,6,4,2,1,3,7,7,7,7,7,7,7};

        var orderedGroups = testList.GroupBy(x => x)
                                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
                                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());


        var maxElements = orderedGroups.First().Value.Count;


        foreach (var x in orderedGroups.Skip(1))
        {       
            int yMax = maxElements - x.Value.Count;

            for (int y = 0; y < yMax; y++)
            {
                x.Value.Add(0); // Adding default as 0
            }
        }


    orderedGroups.Dump(); // Linqpad print call, replace with console or similar call in the visual studio
```